# Android ListView with 5 different layouts

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new to android and don't know how to make a ListView with more than 1 layout. I need 5 different layouts in the same ListView. The list won't have more than 5 items each with a different layout. 
Also will there be a problem if one layout is a VideoView?

I don't have any code to post, sins I didn't know where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Can you get to the xml layout screen?

Comment: Use an Adapter to your listView. On the Adapter constructor, create a parameter to identify wich type of view you will get. On getView() method inflate your view from the XML layout according to that value.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) and [`getItemViewType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) in your adapter.

The `getViewTypeCount()` would return 5 and `getItemViewType()` would determine what type of view (out of the 5) is to be displayed.

Comment: Do you have a example code fort this? And what is about the VideoView, will it make and problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, go to the relevant xml layout in the /res/layout folder (for MainActivity.java it might be activity_main.xml). From here you can add views/layouts inside your ListView by dragging them onto the ListView in the 'stucture' window to the right of your screen. 
They will be in the order you place them, top to bottom.
You can get your viewslayouts from the widgets panel or add them programatically in Java (do this in the corresponding Java file).

Alternatively, you can write your views/layouts in using xml, make sure they are **between** the ListView tags so it **contains** them.